# Spin-Spin Interaction: Ground State Degeneracy

Tags: quantum-spin, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, ferromagnetism, ground-state

I'm given the hamiltonian $$\hat{H}=\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}\hat{\mathbf{S}}_i\cdot\hat{\mathbf{S}}_{i+1}$$ (reminiscent of a para- or ferromagnetism situation?) where $\hat{\mathbf{S}}_i\cdot\hat{\mathbf{S}}_{i+1}$ is shorthand for $$\hat{\mathbf{S}}_i\cdot\hat{\mathbf{S}}_{i+1}\equiv\hat{1}_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\hat{1}_{i-1}\otimes\hat{\mathbf{S}}_i\otimes\hat{\mathbf{S}}_{i+1}\otimes\hat{1}_{i+2}\cdots\hat{1}_{L}$$ and I'm told that one of its ground state eigenkets is $$\underbrace{|{\uparrow}\rangle\cdots|{\uparrow}\rangle}_{\text{$L$ copies}}\equiv\underbrace{|{\uparrow}\rangle\otimes\cdots\otimes|{\uparrow}\rangle}_{\text{$L$ copies}}.$$ Given this information I should be able to infer the ground state's degeneracy, but I really don't know where to begin. Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are they spin-half operators?

Comment: Given the spin up symbol, I assume so.